# How to position child element fixed in Vue?

Tags: css, vue.js, position, fixed

I am having trouble figuring out why an element will not stay fixed relative to it's parent in Vue. It's only relative to #app. How can I get a child element to be 100% of it's parent in Vue with a position of fixed.

HTML:

```
 <div id="app">
   <div class="parent_relative">
     <div class="child_fixed"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent_relative{
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid green;  
}
.child_fixed{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: blue; 
}
```

The picture below is what it looks like:
[image]

The search bar has a div around it with position fixed. It should not be on the top of the browser. It should be within the dark div that you see below it.

Comment: Remove `top` and `bottom` from the css for `child_fixed`

Comment: What's the issue with `position: absolute`?

Comment: Did removing the top and bottom helps you?

Answer (score 1):

An element with `position: fixed;` is relative to the viewport, not the parent. Maybe, what you're searching for is `position: absolute;` which is relative to it's parent.

Comment: Well I'm trying to get the search bar to be fixed in that parent div. However, position of absolute wont allow that to happen. Do you have any other ideas how this could be achieved?

Comment: One solution is to add a child element to `.child_fixed` with `position: fixed;` and change `.child_fixed` to `position: absolute;`. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pistevw/d8x9utcL/1/) and let me know it it was of any help.